# Random website will stop loading until I restart my computer

Tags: website

I'm having this problem where certain websites (including cnn.com, netflix.com, steampowered.com and espn.com) will always fail to load until i restart my computer. It'll work after the restart, but then after a little bit, these websites will stop loading again. It's been happening more and more frequently, and it's getting frustrating because these are all websites I frequently visit. I don't know why this has been happening, and any potential solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Dell Studio 14, Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: The only website I see there that doesn't use flash is netflix but it may be worth looking what settings it has that could cause a problem with the cache of the browser.

Comment: What browser are you using (Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, ...) And what happens when the sites fail to load: does the browser hang forever? Does it show an error message? If there is an error message, copy-paste it into your question.

Comment: It happens using all browsers. I'm not on that comp right now, but it displays the standard browser "server not found" message, like this: http://tangiblebits.files.wordpress.com/2008/02/server_not_found.png